# nginx - configuration issue - production mode - code 403

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, http-status-code-403, thin

I want to configure NGINX with Rails 4 and run my application in production mode. The problem is I get 403 code - command: `rails s -e production` and in browser typing `localhost`. Naturally I established `755` privileges for the whole files in my application folder. There is my nginx.conf below:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include               mime.types;
    # include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    # include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
    default_type          application/octet-stream;

    sendfile              on;

    keepalive_timeout     65;
    client_max_body_size  50M;

    # fastcgi_buffers 8 16k;
    # fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    # fastcgi_connect_timeout 300;
    # fastcgi_send_timeout 300;
    # fastcgi_read_timeout 300;

    upstream proxy-user {
        server 127.0.0.1:2000;
    }

    upstream thin_cluster {
        server unix:/tmp/thin.0.sock;
       # server unix:/tmp/thin.1.sock;
       # server unix:/tmp/thin.2.sock;
    }

    server {
        listen 80;
        server_name localhost;
        # access_log  /var/log/nginx-access.log;
        root        /home/user/Apps/myapp/public;

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
        try_files $uri @app;
        }

        location /home/user/Apps/myapp/ {
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  Host             $http_host;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_pass        http://proxy-user;

            if (!-f $request_filename) {
              proxy_pass http://proxy-user;
              break;
            }
        }
    }

    server {
        listen                443;
        server_name           _;
        ssl                   on;
        ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
        ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
        ssl_protocols         SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers           HIGH:!ADH:!MD5;
        access_log            /var/log/nginx-access-ssl.log;
        root                  /home/user/Apps/myapp/public;

        location ~* ^.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|css|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|pdf|ppt|txt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf|js|mp3|flv|mpeg|avi)$ {
        try_files $uri @app;
        }

        location /home/user/Apps/myapp/ {
            proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header  X-FORWARDED_PROTO     https;
            proxy_set_header  SSL_CLIENT_S_DN       $ssl_client_s_dn;
            proxy_set_header  Host                  $http_host;
            proxy_redirect    off;
            proxy_pass        http://proxy-user;
        }

        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;

        location = /50x.html {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have you setup Passenger or unicorn?

Comment: No, I haven't setup any of them, I use "thin" as my web server.

Comment: why `location /home/user/Apps/myapp/` ? it should be `location /`

Answer (score 0):

You kinda have few issues in your config, I'll write what I would have done and you tell me what ever questions you have, I'll assume that the server is on port 2000 because that's the upstream you used.

I'll also ignore the http block and only use the server and upstream blocks.

```
upstream rails {
    server 127.0.0.1:2000;
}
server {
  server_name domain.com; # or whichever
  listen 80;

  # ssl settings start
  listen 443 ssl;
  ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/server.crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/server.key;
  # ssl settings end

  root /home/user/Apps/myapp/public;
  error_page 500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/domain-access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/domain-error.log;

  location @pass_to_rails {
    proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP             $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For       $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header  X-FORWARDED_PROTO     $scheme;
    proxy_set_header  Host                  $http_host;
    proxy_redirect    off;
    proxy_pass        http://rails;
  }

  location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @pass_to_rails;
  }
}
```

You should place this inside `sites-available` and symlink to `sites-enabled` if you are on a debian/ubuntu distro, or use `/etc/nginx/conf.d` if you are on another distro, to keep things tidy and maintainable.

also make sure to uncomment one of those lines depending on what you want to use

```
# include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
# include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```